# splitting the address column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, delimiter

I have a pandas dataset like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id':  ['001', '002', '003','004'],
        'address': ["William J. Clare\\n290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA",
                    "1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA",
                    "William N. Barnard\\n145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA",
                    "215 S 11th ST"],
        'locality': [None, None, None,'Laramie'],
        'region': [None, None, None, 'WY'],
        'Zipcode': [None, None, None, '87656'],
        'Country': [None, None, None, 'US']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried to split the address column by new line but however since it has two \ followed by n. I am not able to do . Please help me in splitting the \n from address and exptrapolate into locality region zipcode and country.

sample output:

```
id  address locality    region  Zipcode Country
1   290 Valley Dr.  Casper  WY  82604   USA
2   1180 Shelard Tower  Minneapolis MN  55426   USA
3   145 S. Durbin   Casper  WY  82601   USA
4   215 S 11th ST   Laramie WY  87656   US
```

I tried different methods to split \n using split command but it gives me extra \. And I am trying to keep it in pandas dataframe so that I can carry further analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) instead of split and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) in place:

```
df.update(df['address'].str.extract(r'([^,]+)(?:,\s(\w+)\s*(\d+)\\n(\w+))?$')
 .set_axis(["address", "region", "Zipcode", "Country"], axis=1) 
 )

df['name'] = pd.NA

df.update(df['address'].str.extract(r'(?:(.*?)\\n)?(.*)\\n(.+)')
          .set_axis(['name', 'address', 'locality'], axis=1)
         )
```

output:

```
    id             address     locality region Zipcode Country                name
0  001      290 Valley Dr.       Casper     WY   82604     USA    William J. Clare
1  002  1180 Shelard Tower  Minneapolis     MN   55426     USA                <NA>
2  003       145 S. Durbin       Casper     WY   82601     USA  William N. Barnard
3  004       215 S 11th ST      Laramie     WY   87656      US                <NA>
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SvitJy/1)

Comment: Hi mazway thank you for your response but however i need to retain 4th line locality, region zip and country.

Comment: Hi Mozway thank you for your update. Can you also help me how to pop name and add one part of locality where there is address and update it to address column.

Comment: in line 1 and 3

Comment: I am greatful for your help but if I can crack tis it will be helpful for my analysis

Answer (score 0):

Line two has no name so it may cause some trouble. Please check if your example is correct.

Given your df like this:

```
data = {'id':  ['001', '002', '003','004'],
        'address': ["William J. Clare\\n290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA",
                    "name\\n1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA",
                    "William N. Barnard\\n145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA",
                    "215 S 11th ST"],
        'locality': [None, None, None,'Laramie'],
        'region': [None, None, None, 'WY'],
        'Zipcode': [None, None, None, '87656'],
        'Country': [None, None, None, 'US']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You can create a filter condition:

```
cond = df[["locality", "region", "Zipcode", "Country"]].isna()
```

and then use `split` with `expand=True`

```
df.loc[cond.all(axis=1)].address.str.split(r"\\n", expand=True)

0    William J. Clare      290 Valley Dr.       Casper, WY 82604  USA
1                name  1180 Shelard Tower  Minneapolis, MN 55426  USA
2  William N. Barnard       145 S. Durbin       Casper, WY 82601  USA
```

Comment: hi bitflip, i have already done split and expand, but its not the output which i wanted and i am not sure how will you split and expand when 2nd value which doesnot have name

Comment: yes some lines does not have names so i used

Comment: ```for element in df['address']:
    if not element[0][0].isdigit():
        element.pop(0)```