# Splitting a full UK address with escape characters

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'first_name': ["John", "Mary", "Phillip", "Judith", "Barry"],
        'last_name': ["Cummins", "Lamb", "Windsor", "Garland", "From Eastenders"],

        'address_full': ["12 Walter Cobb Drive\nSutton Colefield\nB73 5QR",
                         "Flat 5a, 90 Shoot Up Hill\nLondon\nNW2 3XJ",
                         "10 Highgate Avenue\nLondon\nLondon\nN6 5RX",
                         "146 Scotland Road\nCambridge\nCB4 1QQ",
                         "11 Earl Close,\r\nDersingham\nKings Lynn\nNorfolk\nPE31 6XZ"],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to have `address_full` separated so it looks like this:

| first_name | last_name | address_1 | address_2 | city_town | county | postcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Cummins | 12 Walter Cobb Drive |  | Sutton Colefield |  | B7 5QR |
| Mary | Lamb | Flat 5a, 90 Shoot Up Hill |  | London |  | NW2 3XJ |
| Phillip | Windsor | 10 Highgate Avenue |  | London |  | W2 3XJ |
| Judith | Garland | 146 Scotland Road |  | Cambridge |  | N6 5RX |
| Barry | From Eastenders | 11 Earl Close | Dersingham | Kings Lynn | Norfolk | PE31 6XZ |

**Challenges**

- Creating an effective regex that captures everything separately and excludes the \r and \n break characters
- The place immediately before the postcode could be a `county` or a `city_town` and so asigning to a new column may cause these values to be placed in the incorrect column.

This similar question has been helpful—[splitting the address column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121651/splitting-the-address-column-in-pandas). However I've been struggling with getting the regex to capture everything.

This is my attempt so far—https://regex101.com/r/aMqyIY/1.

I have the postcode, the final element of each address, and in some cases address_1. But I'm struggling to capture all of the separate elements within the last address in my example, despite the use of the `{2,}` quantifier.

Any assistance very gratefully received!

Comment: This kind of parsing is basically impossible using regular expressions for arbitrary data. You need to have a list of valid post codes, valid towns and counties, and consume those elements out. Then extract the address, leaving a name. The name will basically never be well behaved (eg "David Lloyd George").

Comment: Thanks @ifly6. I'll take a look at some of the parsing options with pypostal.